# How to gain weight?

Tags: bodybuilding

19 years old .Height 5'9 , weight 45. It is my first attempt. I am a Gamer. I don't go out much. Got dumped For being a thin person,just yesterday. Help please.

Comment: You've already asked this here: http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/29634/how-to-gain-weight-for-a-thin-person. But apparently you've managed to lose 4 kilograms in that short span of time.

Comment: 45 what?I hope you mean kg which still does not make sense

Answer (score 0):

Start with a **CONSISTENT** **diet** first. This means that at certain times of the day you will eat a certain amount of food.

It doesnt matter what you will eat. Weigh yourself every day. If the weight stays within a 1kg tolerance you can safely say you are "maintaining" your weight.

If you want to gain weight increase the amount of food you eat e.g an extra meal before you go to bed or having half a plate of fries instead of quater and do it for a week weighing yoruself every day. Then just increase/deacrease the amount of meals or food to suit your goal.